# Android 7.0 Not able to get list of files under "/" directory

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat, android-7.1-nougat

Before Android 7.0, i was able to get list of files under `"/"` directory, but on Andorid 7.0 version i am getting null when i try t get list of files from `"/"` directory.

Below is my code:

```
File root = new File("/");
File[] files = root.listFiles();
```

Comment: Its the proto rom?

Comment: No i am having stock ROM on nexus 6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From android 7.0 they have applied more restrictions. Now you need to get access for individual directories.

Check [this](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/scoped-directory-access.html) link out for more information.

Comment: i read the mentioned url, and also tried to get StorageVolume instance, but it only provide access to predifined directories, i am unable to get access to "/" directory using StorageVolume framework.

Comment: Check this out https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=205565

Answer (score 3):

I was facing a similar issue with Android 7.0. Try using "/storage/emulated/0" instead of "/". You should get all the files in your phone storage.

You can also use

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Environment.getRootDirectory()` replace it!

Comment: That's not useful it returns /system, which is not required.